# Inserting hyperlinks to UIAlertController's message text (Xamarin.iOS)

Tags: xamarin.ios, dialog, uialertcontroller

UIAlertController uses an UILabel to display text, and I have read that only UITextViews can show clickable links.
I would replace the label in the dialog, however as soon as I remove it, the program throws an error that its constraint cannot be activated.
To remove that constraint, I cycled through the UILabel's superviews, but it is not to be found.
Does anyone have had success with it?

```
UIAlertController dialog = UIAlertController.Create("", message, UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert);
dialog.AddAction(UIAlertAction.Create("OK", UIAlertActionStyle.Default, null));

UILabel label = (UILabel)dialog.View.Subviews[0].Subviews[0].Subviews[0].Subviews[0].Subviews[0].Subviews[2];
UIView view = label;

do
{
    view = view.Superview;

    Console.WriteLine(view);

    foreach (NSLayoutConstraint constraint in view.Constraints)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Constraint: " + constraint.FirstItem + " --- " + constraint.FirstAttribute + " --- " + constraint.SecondItem + " --- " + constraint.SecondAttribute + " --- " + constraint.Constant);
        if (constraint.FirstItem == label)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("FirstItem found");
            view.RemoveConstraint(constraint);
        }
        if (constraint.SecondItem == label)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("SecondItem found");
            view.RemoveConstraint(constraint);
        }
    }

} while (view != dialog.View);

//label.RemoveFromSuperview();
```

Comment: (UILabel)dialog.View.Subviews[0].Subviews[0].Subviews[0].Subviews[0].Subviews[0].Subviews[2];
UIView view = label; - just don't do it. It may change in any version of iOS (even minor) and your app may crash.

Comment: In last case I will use a custom dialog. It just takes a lot to make it look and behave like the in-built one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, you can just change the label's visibility, and insert the textview. As Ivan pointed out, it is good to have a backup solution.

```
UIAlertController dialog = UIAlertController.Create("", message, UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert);
dialog.AddAction(UIAlertAction.Create("OK", UIAlertActionStyle.Default, null));

try
{
    UILabel label = (UILabel)dialog.View.Subviews[0].Subviews[0].Subviews[0].Subviews[0].Subviews[0].Subviews[2];
    label.Hidden = true;                

    UITextView textView = new UITextView();
    dialog.View.Subviews[0].Subviews[0].Subviews[0].Subviews[0].Subviews[0].InsertSubviewAbove(textView, label);

    textView.TranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false;
    textView.LeadingAnchor.ConstraintEqualTo(label.LeadingAnchor).Active = true;
    textView.TopAnchor.ConstraintEqualTo(label.TopAnchor, -8).Active = true;

    textView.BackgroundColor = UIColor.FromRGBA(0, 0, 0, 0);
    textView.ScrollEnabled = false;
    textView.Editable = false;
    textView.DataDetectorTypes = UIDataDetectorType.Link;
    textView.Selectable = true;
    textView.Font = UIFont.SystemFontOfSize(13);
    textView.Text = message;            
}
catch
{
}

context.PresentViewController(dialog, true, null);
```